# Dynamic Variables that can Execute in R

Tags: r

I like to create separate variables in R which each read different tables as below:

```
AA_1_11 <- read.table(File_AA_1_11.dta,header=TRUE))
AA_2_22 <- read.table(File_AA_2_22.dta,header=TRUE))
AA_3_33 <- read.table(File_AA_3_33.dta,header=TRUE))
AA_4_44 <- read.table(File_AA_4_44.dta,header=TRUE))
BB_1_11 <- read.table(File_BB_1_11.dta,header=TRUE))
BB_2_22 <- read.table(File_BB_2_22.dta,header=TRUE))
BB_3_33 <- read.table(File_BB_3_33.dta,header=TRUE))
BB_4_44 <- read.table(File_BB_4_44.dta,header=TRUE))
```

Through [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120427/dynamic-variables-in-r), I have managed to create separate variables and assign a numerical value, *x* to each. The x could be easily replaced with an equation of a function of x, *f(x)*,

```
char_list <- c("AA", "BB")
num_list <- c("1_11", "2_22", "3_33", "4_44")
x <- 1
for (char in char_list) {
  for (num in num_list) {   
    assign(paste(char,num, sep = '_'), x)  
    x <- x + 1
  }
}
```

The same approach seems does not work for the below. It is not executing reading a table.

```
char_list <- c("AA", "BB")
num_list <- c("1_11", "2_22", "3_33", "4_44")
for (char in char_list) {
  for (num in num_list) {   
    temp <- paste('"D:/File_',ant,'_',sta,'.dta"',sep = '')
    assign(paste(char,num, sep = '_'), read.table(temp,header=TRUE))  
  }
}
```

From HELP library - The assign(x, value) syntax not sure if *value* only applies to numbers.

Can you please guide if there is other way to create separate variables and execute to read different read tables by each of the variable?

Update: List 
Experimented suggestion by @Roland. Did not quite get if this was what suggested.

```
char_list <- c("AA", "BB")
num_list <- c("1_11", "2_22", "3_33", "4_44")

char_num_list <- list()

for (char in char_list) {
  char_num_list[[char]] <- list()
  for (num in num_list) {
    char_num_list[[char]][[num]] <- paste('"D:/File_',char,'_',num,'.dta"',sep = '')
    assign(paste(char,num, sep = '_'), read.table(char_num_list[[char]][[num]],header=TRUE))  
  }
}
```

Comment: This comes up here again and again. Put your data.frames in a `list`.

Comment: @Roland Sorry if this came again. I tried experimenting and updated the codes above. Do check if I have done correctly as suggested. If this had been asked before can you please point the link as I have not been lucky when searching for it in the database. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using a list there is no need to use `assign` as well. The whole idea of putting everything in a list is to avoid setting variables with `assign`.

Example data.frame since I cannot read your files:

```
a <- data.frame(a=runif(50))
```

**Solution**

```
char_list <- c("AA", "BB")
num_list <- c("1_11", "2_22", "3_33", "4_44")

char_num_list <- list()

for (char in char_list) {
  char_num_list[[char]] <- list()
  for (num in num_list) {
    temp <- paste('"D:/File_',char,'_',num,'.dta"',sep = '') #save the path for each file
    char_num_list[[char]][[num]] <- a #I am using a here but you should be using your read.table   
  }
}
#replace a with read.table(temp,header=TRUE) for your tables
```

**Output:**

```
> str(char_num_list)
List of 2
 $ AA:List of 4
  ..$ 1_11:'data.frame':    50 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ a: num [1:50] 0.24 0.383 0.89 0.675 0.736 ...
  ..$ 2_22:'data.frame':    50 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ a: num [1:50] 0.24 0.383 0.89 0.675 0.736 ...
  ..$ 3_33:'data.frame':    50 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ a: num [1:50] 0.24 0.383 0.89 0.675 0.736 ...
  ..$ 4_44:'data.frame':    50 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ a: num [1:50] 0.24 0.383 0.89 0.675 0.736 ...
 $ BB:List of 4
  ..$ 1_11:'data.frame':    50 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ a: num [1:50] 0.24 0.383 0.89 0.675 0.736 ...
  ..$ 2_22:'data.frame':    50 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ a: num [1:50] 0.24 0.383 0.89 0.675 0.736 ...
  ..$ 3_33:'data.frame':    50 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ a: num [1:50] 0.24 0.383 0.89 0.675 0.736 ...
  ..$ 4_44:'data.frame':    50 obs. of  1 variable:
  .. ..$ a: num [1:50] 0.24 0.383 0.89 0.675 0.736 ...
```

As you can see by using a list you do not use assign at all, which will make your life easier anyway.